# why am i getting MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms when using mongodb-memory-server with jest

Tags: testing, mongoose, jestjs

I have a nodejs project in which i am trying to run some test with jest using mongodb-memory-server as the database but i keep getting `MongooseError: Operation` users.findOne() `buffering timed out after 10000ms` whenever i test database related things.

This is my package.json file

```
{
    "name": "auth",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "ts-node-dev --poll src/index.ts",
        "test": "jest --watchAll --no-cache"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "ts-jest",
        "testEnvironment": "node",
        "setupFileAfterEnv": [
            "./src/test/setup.ts"
        ]
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/cookie-session": "^2.0.44",
        "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
        "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.1",
        "cookie-session": "^2.0.0",
        "express": "^4.18.2",
        "express-async-errors": "^3.1.1",
        "express-validator": "^6.15.0",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
        "mongoose": "^7.0.3",
        "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
        "typescript": "^4.9.5"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/jest": "^29.5.0",
        "@types/supertest": "^2.0.12",
        "jest": "^29.5.0",
        "mongodb-memory-server": "^8.12.1",
        "supertest": "^6.3.3",
        "ts-jest": "^29.0.5"
    }
}
```

i'm using mongodb-memory-server@8.12.1

i expect my tests to pass and i expect data to be fetched from the database.

i try downgrading the mongodb-memory-server package but still got the same result

Answer (score 0):

i've been able to get this to work after 5 hours of battling with this issue... the issue was in my package.json file in the jest block. i use **setupFileAfterEnv** instead of **setupFilesAfterEnv**. Please check that place out if you are having this issue. thanks

Answer (score 0):

To fix, make sure you call mongoose.connect() if you're defining models by calling mongoose.model():

```
async function run() {
await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017');
mongoose.model('User', schema);

await mongoose.model('User').findOne();
```

}

try it